# Load css/js for specific User Control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to load a css/js only when a specific user control is being used.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Two separate answers: for the javascript you need to use the script manager on the page (or pages) you want to add this control to.. On the control(s), include a script proxy. These are designated as "ajax extensions" but they work for any script. The manager will insure that only one instance of any particular script is loaded.

on the page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

on the control .ascx

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

on the code behind for the control

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ScriptManagerProxy1.Scripts.Add(new ScriptReference(@"../path/yourJavascript.js"));
}
```

Ok, as for the CSS that is even easier, on the control include a link to the style sheet:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../css/yourStyleSheet.css' />
```

another option if you have a 'relative path issue' for you .ascx:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/yourStyleSheet.css") %>' />
```